# How to Read Chrome Dev Tools Performance Profiling --> Network Tab?

Tags: performance, networking, google-chrome-devtools

In the network dropdown after profiling a website the data is shown with thin white lines coming before and after the data. What do these thin white lines indicate?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This data is interpreted using the axis on the top of the profiler and the color legend in the summary tab of the profiler output. [Refer to this screenshot of a profile I took of this page for added clarity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z6uq.png)

---

By looking near the top of the profile (immediately above the network profile dropdown ) you will see an axis that corresponds to the time since the start of the page request. Everything is measured in milliseconds (abbreviated "ms" in the profiler).

The left edge of the thin line on your requests represents the start time of the request to download the content named in the bar body. (Refer to the .mp4 bars in your image for clear depictions of the left edge of the referenced thin line)

Similarly, the right edge of the thin line on your requests represents the end time of a requested resource. This time includes any downloading, and loading/execution time.

The position of the bars tells you when each resource was loaded relative to the others in the profile and the start time.

---

The colors of the bars are depicted in the legend of the profile's summary tab (refer to my linked image for added clarity). At the time of writing:

1. Loading is blue
2. Scripting is orange
3. Rendering is purple
4. Painting is green
5. System is grey
6. Idle is white

If also helpful for you to visualize you can run this code snippet to see the colors more easily on StackOverflow:

```css
.input-color {
  position: relative;
}

.input-color input {
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.input-color .color-box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #8e8e8e;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-color">
  <input type="text" value="Loading (Blue)" readonly/>
  <div class="color-box" style="background-color: #90b7e9;"></div>
</div>
<div class="input-color">
  <input type="text" value="Scripting (Orange)" readonly/>
  <div class="color-box" style="background-color: #f3d17c;"></div>
</div>
<div class="input-color">
  <input type="text" value="Rendering (Purple)" readonly/>
  <div class="color-box" style="background-color: #af99eb;"></div>
</div>
<div class="input-color">
  <input type="text" value="Painting (Green)" readonly/>
  <div class="color-box" style="background-color: #90c185;"></div>
</div>
<div class="input-color">
  <input type="text" value="System (Grey)" readonly/>
  <div class="color-box" style="background-color: #dedede;"></div>
</div>
<div class="input-color">
  <input type="text" value="Idle (White)" readonly/>
  <div class="color-box" style="background-color: #fafafa;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the difference between the start of the thin white line and the start of the bar it's associated with? One indicates the start of the request (thin white line), and the other (the bar) indicates the start of the content loading?

Comment: The start of the thin white line is when a request was sent out for a resource. A request for the resource is sent out to a server. The thick associated bar begins when your computer receives a response from the server.

Comment: @GavinSiver what about the color difference inside the bar (whits/grey)? is that indicating the download of the response and executing?

Comment: @AlonSegal Not quite, though your thought process is not far off. The download of the resource begins when the resource is Grey; the white indicates the resource, downloaded or otherwise, is not being used by the system at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Google has an official doc to explain this. reference: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/performance/reference/#network

TLDR:

Requests are color-coded as follows:

HTML: Blue
CSS: Purple
JS: Yellow
Images: Green

Visualization meaning:

- The left line is everything up to the Connection Start group of events, inclusive. In other words, it's everything before Request Sent, exclusive.
- The light portion of the bar is Request Sent and Waiting (TTFB).
- The dark portion of the bar is Content Download.
- The right line is essentially time spent waiting for the main thread. This is not represented in the Timing tab.